# how to store asp controls in an array?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, file-upload

I am using 10 asp:fileUpload control to upload multiple files

Now I want to check on each upload that it has file in it or not?

For that I took an array as

`FileUpload uploadarr[] = new FileUpload[10];`

but how do I check that it has posted file or not using 10 controls as
FileUpload1,FileUpload2,FileUpload3...FileUpload10

`HttpPostedFile myFile = FileUpload1.PostedFile;`

Comment: What do you need as the result, true or false for all 10 controls having a file? A list with and without files? A list of the uploaded files?

Comment: I need list of uploaded files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than storing each FileUpload in an array, you could make use of the [HttpRequest.Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files.aspx) property to recurse all files posted to the page like so:

**Markup**

```
<div><asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /></div>
<div><asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" runat="server" /></div>
<div><asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload3" runat="server" /></div>
<asp:Button ID="UploadFilesButton" runat="server" Text="Upload Files" OnClick="UploadFilesButton_Click" />
```

**Code**

```
protected void UploadFilesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = Request.Files;
    for (int fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < uploadedFiles.Count; fileIndex++)
    {
        HttpPostedFile uploadedFile = uploadedFiles[fileIndex];
        string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        {
            //Upload file as required
            //uploadedFile.SaveAs("??");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

With linq, try this:

```
var files = uploadarr.Where(x=>x.HasFile).Select(x=>x.PostedFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

In page .cs file:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        // Panel is ASP panel
        Panel.Controls.Add(new FileUpload());
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var p in Panel.Controls)
    {
        if (p is FileUpload)
            Response.Write(((FileUpload)p).FileName);
    }
}
```